# Excel VBA Sum issue

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I'm trying to sum a column that's located in another worksheet. I'm trying to sum everything from C2 downwards in sheet 2 and putting it into the cell in E4 in sheet 1.

I've had this code that has worked perfectly until now and it still works fine by itself

```
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM('Sheet2'!C[-1]:C[-1])"
```

However, when I now use it I get a 1004 error message that says that its wasn't able to select the cell.

So I tried doing this instead:

```
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM('Sheet2'!C[-1]:C[-1])"
```

So I tried using this code that I found online but it doesn't work either

`Range("E4") = Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C"))`

Any advice on the best way to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking the whole column `C`, I think it's more efficient to find the last row.
An example of how you could do it:

```
Sub Calculate()
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test") 'Change the name of WS accordingly
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data") 'Change the name of WS accordingly

lastrow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row used in column C in sheet 'Data'

ws.Range("E4").Value = Application.Sum(ws2.Range("C2:C" & lastrow))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to sum all of column C in Sheet2, except cell C1
In VBA:

```
Workbook("name of workbook").Sheets(1).Range("E4").Formula = "=SUM(Sheet2!C:C)"
```

If C1 is a number that you need to keep out of the sum, this will check if C1 is a number and then subtract it from the sum total, if it's not a number it will subtract zero

```
Workbook("name of workbook").Sheets(1).Range("E4").Formula = "=SUM(Sheet2!C:C)-IF(ISNUMBER(C1),C1,0)"
```